# Why were they surprised they couldn't send e-mails when the network was closed off in the first place?

Tags: subete-ga-f-ni-naru

In episode 2, Yamane Yukihiro explains that the network on the island is completely isolated, a protected network.

[image: Picture from episode 2: Then how does the lab's network function?][image: Picture from Episode 2: It's completely isolated form the outside world]

If that is the case, why are they surprised when they cannot send e-mails or communicate with the outside world when the system goes down later in episode 3?

[image: Episode 3: lab's network has been cut off]

Comment: Just from a real-world technology perspective, it wouldn't be strange if they had a "main" internal network that was air-gapped from the internet, plus an "auxiliary" network that they used for email and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A network **doesn't have to be public**. **Network** is just a bunch of computers that are able to share their content between each other.

So they weren't able to communicate within their network nor with the outside world.

They probably could communicate to the outside world **before** through a proxy server that is within their control only.

[image]

Image and further explanation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Bypassing_filters_and_censorship)